# unable to see sprite in scene Getting error as floating point precision limitation

Tags: unity, 2d, sprites

I am trying to create game object by dragging image from project window to scene I am getting error as due to floating point precision limitation- it is recommended to bring the world coordinates of game object within smaller range
I am following ruby's adventure tutorial in unity learning

Comment: Have you tried working closer to the world origin, position (0, 0, 0)?

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the GameObject is very far away from the world center. Check its transform in the Inspector. The x, y, or z coordinate is probably greater than 100,000 units. You should never position anything this far from the world origin unless you have a good reason to.